# Retrieving current frame number

Tags: c++, qt, vlc, libvlc

I am doing a project which involves a bit of video recording and editing and I am struggling to find a good C++ library to use. I am using QT as my framework and their video player is not working properly for me to use (seeking crashes some times, e.g.). Also, I need to record video and audio from my camera and QCamera does not work in windows (for recording).

On my program the user can draw on top of the video and I need to store the start frame and the end frame of those drawings.

Right now I've been testing Libvlc which almost does what I want. From what I can see they don't have a way to just jump to a certain frame as this can only be done by time or position.

The first solution that I came up with was to capture the time change event and then calculate the frame using the FPS. The problem is that, as far as I can tell, the interval of this event is around 250ms, which for a 15fps video is almost 4 frames.

So, the second solution was to use libvlc_video_set_callbacks to make my own "lock, unlock and display" and count the frames there. This works for recording from the camera, as there is no going back and the frames go from 0 until the video stops. The problem is when playing a video. Since there is no timestamp, as far as I can tell, there is no way for me to know in which frame number I am (the user can be seeking for example). My "hacky" solution was to have a "lastTime" and "numTimes" on the struct I pass into these callbacks and this is what I do:

lastTime represents the "last new time" received and numTimes represents the number of times lastTime was received.

```
get_the_current_time
calculate_frame_num_with_fps
if current_time is equal to lastTime: 
     frameNum += numTimes
     numTimes++
else 
     lastTime = current_time
     numTimes = 1
```

This kinda works but I hate the solution. I'm not sure if when doing seeking the time changes if the difference is less than 250ms. That would maybe be kinda hard for a user to do but I'd prefer not to implement it like that.

So my question is if there is another, better solution for this?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
I just realized that my solution does not work quite well because even if the video is paused the handlers are all being called, resulting in "current_time == lastTime", which will keep increasing frames when in reality is the same one. I also don't see a way to check if it's the same frame or not. I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The library part was more of an "add-on" to my question, but I've edited it to become more clear.